# Visualforce page save only first record & override case status

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have created a visualforce report page to perform a search on Case object and displayed data in report format. I am trying to InlineEdit "Case Meeting Notes" field.

**Issue 1:** If I try to add text in Case Meeting Notes field for multiple records. Only first record got save.

**Issue 2:**  When I perform search on this VF report, lets say, case xxxx is in Pending Closure status. At the same time, another co-worker updated this particular case xxxx to Closed status. Now, after some time, on the same VF report, when I added text to Case Meeting Notes field and hit Save button. Case Status got override back to Pending Closure.

Can you please guide me where I am getting wrong and what update should I make?

Thanks in advance!

Here is visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="VFC_CasesMultipleSearch" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Details To Search">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputText value="{!cas.SAC__c}" label="Search SAC"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!cas.Product__c}" label="Search Product"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!cas.Service_Level__c}" label=" Search Service Level"/>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cas.CER_Enhancement_Request__c}" label="Enhancement Request?"/>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cas.Status_Closed__c }" label="Status Closed?"/>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cas.Internal_Only__c }" label="Internal Only?"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!cas.From_Closed_Date__c}" label="From Closed Date"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!cas.To_Closed_Date__c}" label="To Closed Date"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
            
            <!---Search Button--> 
            <apex:pageblockButtons html-align="left" location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchCase}"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Details" id="noRec" rendered="{! IF( caseList != null && caseList.size ==0 , true, false)}" >
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <h1>No Records Found </h1>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock> 
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Details" id="details" rendered="{! IF( caseList != null && caseList.size >0, true, false)}" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseList}" var="c">
               
                <apex:column headerValue="Case Number" >
                    <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!c.id}">{!c.CaseNumber}. 
                    </apex:outputLink> 
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.CreatedDate}" headerValue="Created Date"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Product__c}" headerValue="Product"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Version__c}" headerValue="Version"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Environment__c}" headerValue="Environment"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}" headerValue="Subject"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Status}" headerValue="Status"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Severity__c}" headerValue="Priority"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.Contact_Name__c}" headerValue="Case Contact"/>
                
                <apex:column value="{!c.OwnerId}" headerValue="Case Owner"/>
                
               <apex:column value="{!c.Related_Defect__c}" headerValue="Related Defect?"/>

                <apex:column headerValue="Case Meeting Notes">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!c.Case_Comments_On_VFReport__c}">
                     <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="OnClick"/>
                   </apex:outputField>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
     
            
                    <!---Save & Export as Excel Buttons -->
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons html-align="left" location="top">
                          <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                          <apex:commandButton value="Export as Excel" action=" 
                                     {!exportAsExcel}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
                    <!---Next & Previous Buttons -->
                   <apex:pageBlockButtons html-align="left" location="bottom">
                          <apex:commandButton value="Previous" rerender="details" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}" />
                          <apex:commandButton value="Next" rerender="details" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}" />
                   </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is controller:

```
public with sharing class VFC_CasesMultipleSearch {
    
    public Case cas{get;set;}  
    public List<Case> caseList {get;set;}
    List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
    private integer totalRecs = 0;
    private integer offsetSize = 0;
    private integer limitSize= 50;
    
    public VFC_CasesMultipleSearch(){
        cas = new Case();
    }
    
    public void searchCase(){
        totalRecs = 0;
        offsetSize = 0;
        if(caseList !=null && caseList.size()>0){
            caseList=null;
        }
        searchCases ();
        conditions.clear();
    }
    
    //sorting columns logic
    public String sortDir {
        get{
            if(sortDir == null){
                sortDir = 'asc'; 
            } 
            return sortDir;  
        }
        set;
    }
    
    // the current field to sort by. defaults to casenumber
    public String sortField {
        get{ 
            if (sortField == null){
                sortField = 'casenumber'; 
            } 
            return sortField;  
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public void toggleSort() {
        // simply toggle the direction
        sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        // run the query again
        searchCases();
    }
    //end sorting columns logic

    
    //Search button
    public Void searchCases(){
        
        if(caseList != null && !caseList.isEmpty()){
            caseList.clear();
        }
        
        if(cas.From_Closed_Date__c != null){
          String fromDate = cas.From_Closed_Date__c +'';
          fromDate = fromDate.split(' ',0)[0]+'T00:00:00.000Z';
          conditions.add('ClosedDate >='+ fromDate);
      }
      
      if(cas.To_Closed_Date__c  !=null){
          String toDate = cas.To_Closed_Date__c +'';
          toDate = toDate.split(' ',0)[0]+'T23:59:59.000Z';
          conditions.add('ClosedDate <='+ toDate);
      }
       
        if(cas.SAC__c !=null && cas.SAC__c !=''){
            conditions.add('SAC__c =\'' +cas.SAC__c+ '\' ');
        }
        
        if(!String.isEmpty(cas.Product__c)){
            conditions.add('Product__c =\'' +cas.Product__c+ '\' ');
            //system.debug('Product__c =\'' +cas.Product__c+ '\' ');
        }
        
        if(cas.Service_Level__c !=null && cas.Service_Level__c !=''){
            conditions.add('Service_Level__c=\'' +cas.Service_Level__c+ '\'');
        }
        
        if(cas.Status_Closed__c){
            conditions.add('Status_Closed__c=' +cas.Status_Closed__c);
        }else{
            conditions.add('Status_Closed__c=' +cas.Status_Closed__c);
        }
        
        if(cas.CER_Enhancement_Request__c){
            conditions.add('CER_Enhancement_Request__c=' +cas.CER_Enhancement_Request__c);
        }else{
            conditions.add('CER_Enhancement_Request__c=' +cas.CER_Enhancement_Request__c);
        }
        
        if(cas.Internal_Only__c){
            conditions.add('Internal_Only__c=' +cas.Internal_Only__c);
        }else{
            conditions.add('Internal_Only__c=' +cas.Internal_Only__c);
        }
        
         //create a dynamic query for filter results
        String strQuery ='SELECT Id, CaseNumber, CreatedDate, Product__c, Version__c, Environment__c, Status, ClosedDate, Status_Closed__c, Subject, OwnerId, Severity__c, Contact_Name__c, Related_Defect__c, DefectURL__c, Target_Date__c, Case_Comments_On_VFReport__c, SAC__c, CER_Enhancement_Request__c, Service_Level__c FROM Case';
        
        if (conditions.size() > 0) {
            strQuery += '  WHERE  ' + conditions[0];
            for (Integer i = 1; i < conditions.size(); i++){
                strQuery += '  AND  ' + conditions[i];
            }
        }
        
        if(totalRecs !=null && totalRecs ==0){
            List<Case> caseTemp = Database.query(strQuery);
            totalRecs = (caseTemp !=null && caseTemp.size()>0) ? caseTemp.size() : 0;
        }
        
        strQuery += ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' LIMIT :limitSize OFFSET :offsetSize';
        caseList = Database.query(strQuery);
        
    }// end Search button
    
    // Save button
    public PageReference save(){
        try{
            Database.upsert(caseList, false);
            system.debug('caseList'+ caseList);
            return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
        }
        catch(DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,e.getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }//end Save button
    
    //Export button
    public PageReference exportAsExcel(){
        PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('/apex/VFP_CaseReportExportPage');
        return vfPage;
    }
    
    // previous button
    public void previous()
    {
        offsetSize = (offsetSize-limitSize);
        searchCases();
    }
    
    // next button
    public void next(){
        offsetSize = offsetSize + limitSize;
        searchCases();
    }
    
    public boolean getprev(){
        if(offsetSize == 0){ 
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean getnxt(){
        if((offsetSize + limitSize) > totalRecs){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is ~50% larger than it should be if well optimized. You may want to search around here on SFSE to learn some tricks on optimization.

Answer (score 0):

After saving, you need to perform a "search" again to get the latest values from the database. Redirecting to "ApexPages.currentPage()" won't update the records in the page memory.

```
public void save(){
    for(Database.UpsertResult result: Database.upsert(caseList, false)) {
      if(!result.isSuccess()) {
        return; // show errors
      }
    }
    // Everything saved okay, refresh page
    searchCases();
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox! Thank you for your response. I did add your suggestion, but it still saving 1st record only. Other consecutive records do not get insert neither get updated.